# Python: list index out of range even if I am looking at element with index 0

Tags: python

sorry if this question has already been asked but I can't find any answer that solves my problem.
I am using Python 3.8 with PyCharm on Mac (if that information can help).
I just started learning python and have a solid C and MatLab background.
My goal here is to read some information about train stations from a file in the format
   
and then ask the user for a station and give out the names of the stations that are connected by trains. Here is my code:

```
fin = open('trains', 'r')
string = fin.read()
lines = string.split('\n')
print(lines)
station = input("Insert station name\n")
from_station = [] #stations from which trains arrive at the user's station
to_station = [] #stations to which trains arrive from user's station
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    words = lines[i].split()
    for i in range(0,4):
        print(words[i]) #put to check if the words list actually stores the different words
    if words[0] == station:
        to_station.append(words[2])
    if words[2] == station:
        from_station.append(words[0])
print("Trains arriving from stations: ")
print(from_station)
print("Trains going to stations: ")
print(to_station)
fin.close()
```

I keep getting the Index out of bounds error for `print(words[i])` in line 17 even if my complier (or interpreter) manages to print the right informartions without any problem.
I cannot manage to compile the code after the end of the for.

Thank you in advance for your help

EDIT: Even if I make that correction you suggested - I didn't notice in the inner loop that mistake - I still keep getting that error. I get that error even if I remove that inner loop altogether.

[image: This is the image of the code that I run, which is the one above after making the correction suggested in the first answers/comments]

Comment: Are you sure that `words` is an array?

Comment: `for i in range(0,4):
        print(words[i]) `

Well, just for starting, how do you know the length of words? if the length is 2...then you get what you get now

Comment: You second loop is using the same interator `i`
Show the error please

Comment: The inner `i` isn't an issue. The `range` function will return the proper value even with `i` being modified inside the loop. Example: https://ideone.com/QLxDhU

Comment: I know that there are four elements because I know how the input is formatted. I manage to print the content of words, I just get that error once I get out of the outer loop.

Comment: I am pretty confident that words is a list because I get the error of "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: In the screen shot, notice the last item in the list is an empty string. So `words = lines[i].split()` will return an empty list on that one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks! Didn't notice that! You solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is in this line

```
words = lines[i].split()
```

you need to check the `len(words)` each time and need to confirm that `len(words)` is in bound of your indices range
exactly viewing your data can resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable in the inner loop other than 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your inner loop and also the iterator on the list words. You may have a list of two words then can have a Index out of bounds error.

```
fin = open('trains', 'r')
string = fin.read()
lines = string.split('\n')
print(lines)
station = input("Insert station name\n")
from_station = [] #stations from which trains arrive at the user's station
to_station = [] #stations to which trains arrive from user's station
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    words = lines[i].split()
    for j in range(0,len(words)):
        print(words[j]) #put to check if the words list actually stores the different words
    if words[0] == station:
        to_station.append(words[2])
    if words[2] == station:
        from_station.append(words[0])
print("Trains arriving from stations: ")
print(from_station)
print("Trains going to stations: ")
print(to_station)
fin.close()
```